# How to change color of individual canvas dynamically forevery 5 seconds in android?

Tags: android, canvas

I am creating an android application that consists of canvas that creates a circle and i am updating the color of circle for every  3 seconds.But here i want to change the color of individual circle(one after another) dynamically for every 3 seconds please tell me how to do this.This is my activity:

```
package com.developer.milandemoapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;

public class Automode_Activity extends Activity {


    Thread timer;
     boolean Count=true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
    }

    public class MyView extends View{

    Runnable runnable= new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
      invalidate();
    }
    };


    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Handler handler_sec = new Handler();
    public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);


            getWidth();
            getHeight();
            final int radius = 25;
            System.currentTimeMillis();

            final Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            if(Count)  
             {
               paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D50000"));

             }                
             else
             {

              paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#33691E"));
              handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

             }   
            Count=!Count;

            canvas.drawCircle(300, 300, radius, paint);
            canvas.drawCircle(400, 300, radius, paint);
            canvas.drawCircle(500, 300, radius, paint);
            canvas.drawCircle(600, 300, radius, paint);
            canvas.drawCircle(700, 300, radius, paint);
            canvas.drawCircle(800, 300, radius, paint);
            canvas.drawCircle(900, 300, radius, paint);


            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);


            }






        }
}
```

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427288/how-to-change-color-of-canvas-in-android-dynamically-for-every-5-sec

Comment: It doesnt happen dude but here i want to change color of individual circle one by one dynamically @Harry

Comment: Give every circle its own Paint instance. Make them local to the class. Loop through them to see which one has the color. Then reset the color and give the next one the color.